# Does the email_verified field in the Google oAuth ID Token mean that the account has a verified mobile number?

Tags: google-oauth

I would like to know if the email_verified field in the ID Token JWT indicated that the account owner has verified his / her account using a mobile device. This will help avoid sending another SMS to the user for verification.

```
    {"iss":"accounts.google.com",
     "at_hash":"HK6E_P6Dh8Y93mRNtsDB1Q",
     "email_verified":"true",
     "sub":"10769150350006150715113082367",
     "azp":"1234987819200.apps.googleusercontent.com",
     "email":"jsmith@example.com",
     "aud":"1234987819200.apps.googleusercontent.com",
     "iat":1353601026,
     "exp":1353604926,
     "hd":"example.com" }
```

Answer (score 2):

No. This does not indicate that the user has verfied his account using a mobile device.